# What is a proper way to use next_link for pagination in Python?

Tags: python, loops, pagination, python-requests

I'm trying to collect 250 records per 'slice'. In total I have 1429 records, so 6 slices of 250 should be enough to collect all my records. I tried to do this with below code but when I run it it gives me back only the records 251 to 500. My expected result was to receive the records 1 to 1429. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
   import requests
   import json
   import math
       
    res = r.json()
    token = res['access_token']
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    proxies = {'https': 'proxy.***.***.com:8080'}
    mod_date =  'ModifiedOn gt 2020-01-31'
    col = 'Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4'
    
    params1 = (('$count', 'true'),)       
    response1 = requests.get('https://***-***-***.***.nl/odata/***', headers=headers, params=params1, proxies=proxies)
   
    data = response1.json()
            
    next_link = data['@odata.nextLink'] #<--- this is my 'next_link' link.
    total_records = data['@odata.count'] #<--- this are the total records '1429'
    records_per_page = next_link[313:] #<--- this are the records per page '250'
    
    total_pages = total_records / int(records_per_page)  #<--- these are the total pages '5.7'
    
    list_to_store_all_sclices = []
    list_pages = [i for i in range(1, math.ceil(total_pages) +1)] #<--- '5,7' is rounded to 6 and placed in list.
   
    
    for x in list_pages:
        response2 = requests.get(next_link.format(x), headers=headers,  proxies=proxies)
        data = response2.json()
        list_to_store_all_sclices.append(data)
        print(list_to_store_all_sclices)
```

Comment: ```next_link.format(x)``` suggests that there are ```{}``` in ```next_link```  which I doubt.

Comment: @Chillie even if I `remove .format(x)` I still get only the records `251` to `500`

Comment: That is exactly my point. You're not actually requesting any new pages. You keep requesting the same link from your first response beacuse you don't change ```next_link```.

Comment: How can I change it? I suggested it automatically kept taking the next_link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have made two mistakes here:

1. You created a list to populate with `list_to_store_all_sclices = []`
   but you didn't `append` the first result to that list.

You only append the data after the second request is made.

2. You got the next link from the first result. But then you tried to use `format` on it. When you try to format a string that has no square brackets, nothing happens. Try this yourself:

```
link = 'this is a string'
link2 = 'this is {}'
insert = 'some insertion'
print(link.format(insert))
print(link2.format(insert))
```

Check out the documentation on [formatting synthax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) to understand how formatting works.

Since you have not provided more samples of what `next_link` and the server responses actually look like, we can't help you with exact instructions. But we can assume that the server provides a new link with each response. So you need to capture it after getting each response and use it in your request. Otherwise you are just using the same link over and over like in the code you provided.

You code may look something like this:

```
while next_link:
    new_response = requests.get(next_link, headers=headers,  proxies=proxies)
    new_data = new_response.json()
    list_to_store_all_sclices.append(new_data)
    print(list_to_store_all_sclices)
    next_link = new_data.get('@odata.nextLink', None)
```

But you need to look at what exactly `next_link` looks like, so that you know if/how you need to modify it to make a correct request. The interactive shell is a good tool for that.

Edit to answer your questions:

> 1. Now we are just talking about 1429 records, what If I have millions, wouldn't that be to much for python to handle?

This really depends on the size of your records. If, for example, each one is a 10-character string, you should not have problems storing a lot of them in memory. If they are large, you need to start thinking about a way to store your data out of memory (in files or in a database).

> 2. What are your last 2 lines of code doing?(not the print)

Since you had `next_link = data['@odata.nextLink']` I assumed data is a dictionary. Dictionaries have a [get method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). It returns the value of the provided key.

If there is no such key in the dictionary it returns `None` by default in contrast with using square brackets notation to get a key's value, which raises a `KeyError` if the key is not in the dictionary.

You can also specify the value you want to be returned if the requested key is not in the dictionary. I have explicitly used `None` in my example, but you don't have to do that.

> 3. what is your None doing?

The `while` statement repeatedly executes the block of code as long as an expression is true.

`False`, `None`, empty string, empty dict and etc. are all "falsy", which means when the server doesn't provide a `next_link` and our `next_link` variable is `None`, the loop breaks.

You can read more about Truth value testing [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

> with your code I receive the records 251 till 1429. I'm missing the
> first 250 records.

As I've said in 1. in your code you don't append the data from the first response to `list_to_store_all_sclices`.

So you need to create the list, append the first response data to it, and then proceed to the next request. It should look something like this:

```
data = response1.json()
list_to_store_all_sclices = []
list_to_store_all_sclices.append(data)
```

What you also need to think about is that with your code you're creating a list of dictionaries. You may want to think about the structure of the resulting data and how it may affect your future needs and usage of the result.

Comment: your code did exactly what it had to do but I got 3 comments if you like. 1. Now we are just talking about 1429 records, what If I have millions, wouldn't that be to much for python to handle? 2. What are your last 2 lines of code doing?(not the print) 3. what is your None doing?

Comment: Answering these, 1. can just add a counter like while next_link and len(list_to_store_all_slices) < some_max_number. 2. The .get is a python function for dictionaries that will return the element in dict_obj[key] if it exists or otherwise it will return the second argument (in this case, 3. None).  The reason you want a None is that in python you can say if any_object, and if it is not None it will be True and if it none it is False so it's just to evaluate the loop.

Comment: Okay 1 more question.. with your code I receive the records 251 till 1429. I'm missing the first 250 records.

Comment: @Chillie. Last question, what If I want to place everything (so data + newdata in 1 dictionary and work with it outside the loop?

Comment: @Mediterráneo Since I don't know how the data is organised inside ```data``` I can't give you a precise answer. If you need to just loop through the records, make it a list. If you want to access the data by keys, make it a dictionary. It really depends on the way _you_ want your data to be organised. If you provide a mockup of data inside the response, I may be able to suggest something less abstract.

Comment: @Chillie see my last question. Hope I made it clear there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only getting 250 items at a time, and only using the next page once, then you'll only be able to get the next 250 elements, hence 500. Whilst it's generally not considered good practise, since you in general don't know a priori how many elements you can get, I solved this problem recently with this type of structure

```
    json_dict, links = self._retrieve_transactions_json()
    output_list = parse_json_list(json_dict) # this is my function dont
    while links['next'] and ctr < num_transactions: # if there is a next link keep going, get all accounts
         json_dict, links = self._retrieve_transactions_json(links['next']) # ditto my class 
         output_list.extend(parse_json_list(json_dict)) # ditto above
```

Where I constantly get the next up until I've gotten some number of transactions. Hopefully this code pattern helps. The main point here is that each time you get `data` you are going to get a `data['next'] #next page` that you'll need to iterate through until it's either null or whatever the final page returns according to your API spec

Comment: Im sure your code might work for be but I dont understand what your exactly doing. Can we discuss this further in chat?

Comment: Sure, to be honest not entirely sure how to chat :/ , do you have a link?

Comment: haha lol need to figure out how to chat, you know other ways we can chat?

Comment: https://us20.chatzy.com/27657929949345 this should work for us